# How to change firefox profile preference fields like “security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled” in JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

Firefox Version

53.0 (32-bit)

Selenium `3.4.0`

```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = profile.getProfile("Selenium");

    firefoxProfile.setPreference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false);
```

The problem is the third line does nothing.
If i set manaully `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` to `false` in `about:config` this change is not saved in profile.

How can i set it to `false` from `code` in `java` ?

**I saw similiar topic but it was in `Python`.**

Obviously `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` is setting from `about:config` in `Firefox`

Comment: Can you consider updating us what exactly you are trying to do by setting `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` to `false` in simple terms? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB it is a setting from Firefox that is present in about:config
and i want to disable it

Comment: My question is specific, why do you want to `disable` it? What is the implementation of disabling it? How can I test if my code really disables or not? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB `Selenium` runs `Firefox` and i can manually check by entering `about:config` to see if it is enabled or disabled.

I want to disabled it beacuse sometimes selenium missclicks on the notification about it around the login field.

Comment: Can you consider providing a snapshot of what you exactly mean by `on the notification about it around the login field`? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB the question is crystal clear - what i want to do is run `Firefox` from `Selenium` with property `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` set to `false` if you know how to do it let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While working with Selenium 3.4.0 with geckodriver v.0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox 53.x to start with a existing Firefox profile with `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` set to `false` you need to specify `("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false)` through **setPreference** and next you need to pass the Firefox profile through **DesiredCapabilities** Class.

Here is the working code block which sets `"security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled"` to `false` in the Firefox browser:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
    testprofile.setPreference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false);
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
    dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I tried many times and it worked. But less code **now** seems to work too - and that's weird. Thanks

Comment: @yami Glad it works for you. Let me know if you need help where it breaks. Thanks